# How can i test multiple Browsers in one Watir Script using test-unit gem

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver, testunit, selenium-grid2

So this is not about running multiple browsers in parallel. Its the sequentially running IE11, then IE10, then FireFox, ALL of them on different Virtual Machines Connected to Selenium Grid2.

Here is what i have, running ONE browser on ONE VM.

File: example_grid_ie11.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
require "watir-webdriver"

class GoogleSearch < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.ie
    caps.version = "11"
    caps[:name] = "Testing with IE 11"

    @browser = Watir::Browser.new(
    :remote,
    :url => "http://vm-auto.3mhis.vm:4444/wd/hub",
    :desired_capabilities => caps)
  end

  def teardown
    @browser.close
  end

  def test_search
    @browser.goto "google.com"
    @browser.text_field(:name => "q").set "watir"
    @browser.button.click
    @browser.div(:id => "resultStats").wait_until_present
    @browser.screenshot.save ("GoogleSearch_IE11.png")
    assert @browser.title == "watir - Google Search"
  end
end
```

Now, i could not figure out if i can run multiple setup methods and multiple tear-downs, and which Browser to close in teardown.

test-unit gem, gives me a nice result XUnit Style, plus a lot of asserts.

Answer (score 0):

Use Test::Unit 2.x

gem install test-unit

Example:

https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit

multiple setups:

```
class TC_MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def setup # first
      @standard = MyClass.new
   end

   setup # second
   def setup_alpha
      @alpha = MyClass.new
   end

   setup # third
   def setup_beta
      @beta = MyClass.new
   end

   def test_stuff
      assert_true(1 == 1)
   end
end
```

multiple teardowns:

```
class TC_MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def test_stuff
      assert_true(1 == 1)
   end

   def teardown # last
      @standard = nil
   end

   teardown # second
   def teardown_alpha
      @alpha = nil
   end

   teardown # first
   def teardown_beta
      @beta = nil
   end
end
```